# BubbleSort 2D array rows by a specific column values

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a two- dimensional array and i want to bubble sort it rows by array second column value.

I take `Arrival time` and `Service time` values from user and want to bubble sort it by array second column value(`Arrival time`).

First column is for process number.

```
   static int[][] atst = new int[5][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < atst.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Arrival time for process " + i + ": ");
        atst[i][1] = in.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < atst.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter service Times for process " + i + ": ");
        atst[i][2] = in.nextInt();
    }

   System.out.println("Before sorting: " + Arrays.deepToString(atst));

    for (int i = 0; i < atst.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (atst.length - 1); j++) {
            if (atst[j - 1][1] > atst[j][1]) {     // Then swap!
                int[] tempRow = atst[j - 1];
                atst[j - 1] = atst[j];
                atst[j] = tempRow;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("After sorting :" + Arrays.deepToString(atst));

public static void swapRows(int[][] array, int rowA, int rowB) {
    int[] tempRow = array[rowA];
    array[rowA] = array[rowB];
    array[rowB] = tempRow;
}
```

The `swapRows` method works, But it does not sort array completely.

result:

```
Arrival time for process 0: 5
Arrival time for process 1: 4
Arrival time for process 2: 3
Arrival time for process 3: 2
Arrival time for process 4: 1

Enter service Times for process 0: 2
Enter service Times for process 1: 3
Enter service Times for process 2: 4
Enter service Times for process 3: 5
Enter service Times for process 4: 2

Before sorting: [[0, 5, 2, 0, 0], [1, 4, 3, 0, 0], [2, 3, 4, 0, 0], [3, 2, 5, 0, 0], [4, 1, 2, 0, 0]]
After sorting :[[3, 2, 5, 0, 0], [2, 3, 4, 0, 0], [1, 4, 3, 0, 0], [0, 5, 2, 0, 0], [4, 1, 2, 0, 0]]
```

Whereas the result should be like this:

```
[[4, 1, 2, 0, 0],[3, 2, 5, 0, 0],[2, 3, 4, 0, 0],[1, 4, 3, 0, 0],[0, 5, 2, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: You only do one pass over the array.  [Bubblesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) is not O(n) it's O(n^2). You seem to be missing another loop.  Have a look at the linked pseudocode in the wikipedia article and compare to your code.

Comment: @JamesMontagne See question again, i update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your updated code, the bounds of your inner loop are incorrect:

```
for (int j = 1; j < (atst.length - 1); j++) {
```

You are excluding your last element by subtracting 1 here, which is why the rest of the array is sorted except for the last element.  Should be:

```
for (int j = 1; j < atst.length; j++) {
```